# I installed.net 6 but not visible while creating a new project and I can not ..find the class library while creating a new project. I need a solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-6.0, project

I installed.net6 and .net7 on my Visual Studio Community 2022 but while creating a new project on Visual Studio .net 6 and .net7 are visible in the framework drop-down options. Should I uninstall it?

I have not tried anything yet

Comment: Did you install the SDK or the runtime?

Comment: What IS visible in this drop-down? For all we know, you may be looking in the wrong place. This is the sort of issue where a screenshot is appropriate, so we can see what you're seeing. Also, this question has nothing at all to do with C#. If you can't even create a project, you're not at the point where programming language is an issue.

Comment: I have .net framework  2.0 -4.8 visible on the drop-down. I have tried to reload my project and change the target framework but the i got was that the target framework is not installed.but i did install .net 6 from the beginning of the installation

Comment: Yes, i installed the SDK

Comment: Make sure you select "Console application" and _not_ "Console Application (.NET Framework)" in the first step.